# How do I fetch Google Plus share count using cURL multi?

Tags: php, curl

I found the following function that I've been able to use to collect and cache share counts on various social networks. Thus far, I can feed Twitter, LinkedIn, Facebook, and Pinterest URL's in an Array to this function and they all kick back a response that I can parse and get the count from.

In an effort to speed up the process, I recently found this process that uses cURL multi to fetch all the shares at the same time instead of processing one request at a time.

However, the cURL that I had been using for Google Plus has a lot more configuration in order to make it work. Is it possible to get this configuration into this function so that as it's looping through the requests, if it sees Google Plus, it adds all of this information to that specific request, but still runs the request simultaneously to the others?

Here's the cURL multi function that I'm using:

```
function sw_fetch_shares_via_curl_multi($data, $options = array()) {

  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle
  foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // post?
    if (is_array($d)) {
      if (!empty($d['post'])) {
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
      }
    }

    // extra options?
    if (!empty($options)) {
      curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while($running > 0);


  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  // all done
  curl_multi_close($mh);

  return $result;
}
```

The array that I feed into it is basically something like this:

```
$request_url['pinterest'] = 'https://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?url='.$url;
$request_url['twitter'] = 'https://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $url;
```

And so on and so forth for the other networks. I pass those into the cURL multi function, and they send me some json that I can parse and work with.

Here's the configuration for Google Plus that I would like to integrate into the same function so that I can easily pass it in as well:

```
function sw_fetch_googlePlus_shares($url)  {
    $url = rawurlencode($url);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"'.rawurldecode($url).'","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
    $curl_results = curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
    $json = json_decode($curl_results, true);
    return isset($json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'])?intval( $json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'] ):0;
}
```

Can I set up that loop somehow to see if the $id is 'googlePlus', then it adds all this stuff to that particular request? Is it possible to check if it's Google Plus right before the curl_setopts lines and then pass these other ones in instead somehow? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was a lot easier than I thought:

```
function sw_fetch_shares_via_curl_multi($data, $options = array()) {

  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle
  foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    if($id == 'googlePlus'):

        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc");
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"'.rawurldecode($d).'","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]');
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));

    else:    

        $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    endif;


    // extra options?
    if (!empty($options)) {
      curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while($running > 0);


  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  // all done
  curl_multi_close($mh);

  return $result;
}
```

You can now use this function to fetch all five major networks using simultaneous connections instead of one at a time.

For the array, all the other networks require the request URL, but Google Plus has it's request information built into that plugin so it only requires the URL of the page that you want information for.